# Wizard Design for modern UI (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am planning to create a Windows 8.1 store app.

In my app, I need to show a wizard control. Can anyone give me a good example of Wizard implementation in a store app?

I just need the UI design...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back button, content, next button. Very easy and can be found in google images.
[image]